# At what point is a suggested edit too minor?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I got [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4921890) to review, but it went through before I could cast a vote.

In my mind it's too minor to be an edit- it's just adding some italics to an already readable and easy to understand question. The formatting doesn't particularly address any issues or problems with the question. Am I wrong on this? Is this not "too minor" because there's nothing else that can be done to the question to improve it?

My interpretation was that since this edit doesn't address *any* issues in the post, it fits as 'too minor' (emphasis mine):

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be **substantive** improvements **addressing multiple issues** in the post.

Comment: That edit was rubbish. I rolled it back. Putting emphasis around random words is not what edits are meant for.

Comment: Forget too minor, *that* `one` is **invalid**

Comment: And all three approvers were barely out of nappies, reputation wise. This [fits my assertion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220866/146015) perfectly.

Comment: i found that user's all edit was like same. Bolding some words and saying `improved formatting`.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I think the "reject because it's too minor" reason is invalid. I have often found I second guess myself when reviewing minor edits like removing "Thanks", programming language names from the title, etc, or very minor spelling mistakes. They do fall into the description of an edit being too minor:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

...but I myself would often absently edit posts and change small things like this in the interest of improving the overall quality of the site for everyone involved (Google searchers and SO users).

I suppose that once a user has gained enough reputation not to need to have their edits reviewed, it then makes it OK to make edits without moderation that would, in this case, be a reason for rejection for newer users. I'm obviously not talking about the other reasons (invalid edit, vandalism, plagiarism, etc).